# $document.append is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a function which is supposed to attach an image in a specific place on the page.
The function looks like this:

```
// Attaches the image to the garment
var _attachToGarment = function (container, panelId, path) {

    // If we have no path, exit the function
    if (!path || !panelId)
        return;

    // Get our elements
    var element = container[0].querySelectorAll('[id="' + panelId + '"]'),
        img = angular.element('<img class="img-responsive" src="' + path + '" />')[0];

    // If we have an element
    if (element) {

        // Get the dimensions
        var dimensions = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

        // Update the images' style attributes
        img.style.width = dimensions.width + 'px';
        img.style.top = dimensions.top + 'px';
        img.style.left = dimensions.left + 'px';
        img.style.position = 'absolute';

        console.log(img);

        // Append the image to our document
        $document.append(img);
    }
};
```

The problem I have is that the image is not attached to the document anywhere.
If I change the line:

```
$document.append(img);
```

to:

```
container.append(img);
```

The image is attached but obviously in the wrong place.

Does anyone know why **$document.append** wouldn't work?

Comment: I can't see `$document` anywhere in your directive, did you mean the to use a jQuery selector? `$(document).append`?

Comment: nah, $document has been injected into the service, this is angularjs and I am not using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to give it an element to append to.  What are you wanting to append it to?

You need to do something like this:

```
$document.find('body').append(img);
```

Comment: ahh, this might be it. Let me test :)

Comment: it was actually $document.find('body').append(img) but I will mark this as the answer anyway. Got 8 minutes before I can :)